# What should we name our chat room?

Tags: discussion, chat

Many other StackExchange sites have a name for their chatroom.  MSO has "The Tavern," SU has "Root Access," SF has "The Heap," etc.  Our chatroom here is "Physics."  Lame.  We need a better name.

I propose "The h Bar."

Comment: If you do this, be sure to have physics in the subtitle somewhere so that users who manually search for rooms can still find the room.

Comment: @Kevin the h bar - is that part of the Planck constant? 8)
edit it also reminds me of bra-ket notation.. somehow.

Answer (score 22):

I add your excellent suggestion "the h-bar", so that people can vote for it :-)

### **ℏ**

Answer (score 7):

I know I'm late to the party, but I'd like to formally suggest `Schrödinger's Chat` - complete with umlaut.

Comment: Since the room has been named after the top answer here for a long time, I'd say it may be more productive to post a separate question that requests changing the name from what it is now to "Schrödinger's Chat".

Comment: I was directed here by a moderator in [another comment](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9498/choosing-the-name-of-the-chat-room/9534#comment35672_9534). But, I suppose I can do that as well. You're right that it would get more attention that way.

Comment: Sure. I'm certainly not saying it's wrong to post here.

Comment: Until you open the chat, you never know what's being discussed. In fact, _everything_ is being discussed at the same time. Once we join the chat, it becomes what is being discussed.

Comment: @corsiKa We shamelessly stole your idea!

Answer (score 3):

Since our chat room has been named "The Coupling" for a little while, I'm adding that as an option. Vote away.