# I am just a kid can I be on this site?

Tags: discussion

Can I a kid be on this site and ask Questions? I want to but I think they would be silly

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE. Yes, you can ask any question about physics, though please make an effort to research it first e.g. Google it or use Wikipedia. Also note that the sort of physics mentioned in a typical Hollywood blockbuster owes more to fantasy than physics :-)

Comment: If your questions are mostly from grade school physics, that might be a problem. In that case , learning from other resources might be the best option. Access this site when you're stuck and have tried most of the ways available to you for solving a problem.

Comment: No problem, because [all conversations with children will eventually always lead to physics](https://www.scq.ubc.ca/a-dialogue-with-sarah-aged-3-in-which-it-is-shown-that-if-your-dad-is-a-chemistry-professor-asking-%E2%80%9Cwhy%E2%80%9D-can-be-dangerous-5/)

Comment: If you're under 13, there's a workaround: ask your parent / guardian to create an account and then ask them to post questions and answers on your behalf. So long as _your_ real name isn't on the site and any PII (e.g. email address) belongs to your parent / guardian, it's fine.

Comment: @JohnRennie Your last sentence is yet to be realised by many of my friends.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[Only people aged thirteen years and older may maintain accounts](https://stackexchange.com/legal).

Apart from that, you're welcome to ask whatever you like.  Keep in mind that we'll hold your questions to the same standards as everyone else's --- that is, we won't treat you specially because you're young --- which may mean that your questions get downvoted or closed for reasons that aren't obvious to you.

Comment: To be honest, reasons to close an issue _should_ be clear. Even if you're a kid. Perhaps we should say"We apply the same standards. That means we expect you to check the [Help Center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help) first. If you ignore that, you might find your questions downvoted or closed.".

Comment: Of course you're right. However, now that I'm a moderator I interact more often with people who *should* understand why they keep getting questions and answers deleted, but don't.

Comment: A corollary of this is that you're expected to behave like an adult.  There have been incidents on other Stack Exchange sites where very young users (I guess I mean children) have thrown tantrums when they don't get the answers they want to their questions.  The moderators tend not to tolerate this.

Answer (score 17):

Yeah, you can. (As long as you're 13 or up, as rob said.)

I'm a kid too (ahem, *teenager*, but whatever), and I love this site. I've asked some pretty darn "silly" questions (or at least, ones I thought were silly) but no one has treated me poorly (or differently, for that matter) because of my age. Once you get enough rep, check out the hbar - lots of people there are willing to help and have helped me.

So, give it a go! Learn physics and math and whatever else you may be interested in, and use this site to help you out! You never know what you might learn along the way.

Comment: what is an hbar?

Comment: @SakazukiAkainu Heather is referring to the site chatroom, called [The h Bar](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar). We [know](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9501/8563), it's witty.

Comment: My university's postgrad bar is called h-Bar...

Comment: @SakazukiAkainu They passed up the glorious opportunity to call it Schrodinger's Chat...

Comment: @corsiKa "Where you can't tell if anyone is there until they start talking."

Comment: I'd have to agree with @corsiKa.  Exactly half of all the times I go to the h-bar, it's completely dead.

Answer (score 4):

I started using this site when I was around 16, because I had already studied topics up to quantum field theory, and did not have people that could help me except those online.

I found the physics SE was a great resource, both the existing questions and the body of experienced users that were able to address mine. I also got a lot of satisfaction from helping other people. I was never treated any differently because of my age.

As others have said, it may take you some time to learn how to formulate a question that will be well-received and fit all the guidelines, but I and I am sure other users will be happy to provide any support. When we downvote or close, we give suggestions for improvement.