# Is it okay to get into a long to and fro discussion in the comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, chat

Is it okay to get into a long [to and fro](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=definition&as_epq=to+and+fro) discussion in the comments, with the user asking the question?

If that is not okay, then where can we discuss? I have seen some comment threads are imported into chatrooms by moderators. Is that something only moderators can do? Or can we create our own chatrooms to discuss one-on-one with the OP?

Answer (score 9):

Comments aren't a good medium for back-and-forth; that's that chat is for.  There's a [Chat FAQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq) which is useful to re-read once a year or so.  The privileges of [talking in chat](/help/privileges/chat) and [creating chat rooms](/help/privileges/chat-rooms) come pretty early in the [privilege hierarchy](/help/privileges).

If you leave a comment with the text

> `Let us continue this discussion in [chat]`

then the [special comment markdown](/editing-help#comment-formatting) will make `[chat]` a link to [the main Physics chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71).  [Some guidance](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11090/44126).

If you have enough comment back-and-forth on a particular post, the comment box develops a highlight that suggests, with a link, moving your discussion to a chat room. That chat room starts with a link to the parent post and is populated with the previous comments. Users who don’t have the “talk in chat” privilege yet can participate in the conversation anyway, but [apparently moderator intervention](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/257949/1650379) is required; raise a custom flag on the post and explain what’s happening.

The diamond moderators can create such a post-associated room any time, but we can only migrate the comments once.  This happens most frequently when we get an automated flag that a post has accumulated lots of comments in a short time.  Sometimes a user will manually flag a comment thread that needs attention before.

Note that, while chat is a better tool for real-time back-and-forth than comments, you can use [chat pings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295855/280545) to make chat asynchronous as well.

Comment: Moderators on every site say this, but aside from the "move to chat" feature, there is really no good way to start a chat about a post. Therefore discussions must happen in the comments first and then be moved to chat.